# In how many ways can two disjoint groups of 8 and 7 persons be made from 50 people?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, multinomial-theorem

My approach:

Since the groups are disjoint, I have to find out the number of ways I can group 8 persons out of 50. Then, multiply it with the number of ways I can take 42 people out of 50 (subtracting the 8 people I already took in a group and making both groups disjoint). Which is = **$\binom{50}{8} .\binom{42}{7}$**

But the book says:
 $\dfrac{50!}{8!.7!}$ which is greater than my answer.

Whats wrong with my initial approach?

Comment: Both answers are wrong. But your answer is close. Just divide by 2 because (A, B) is same partition as (B, A)

Comment: @pooja The two groups are not interchangeable, since one is size 8 and the other is size 7. Division by $2$ would be appropriate if it were two groups of the same size.

Comment: Ah right! I see dividing by 2 isn't appropriate here. Thanks @alex.jordan :)

Comment: $\dfrac{50!}{7!\,8!\,35!} \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer seems right to me. And it matches the book's if you put a $35!$ in the denominator. It could simply be a mistake in what is printed.

What if it were two disjoint groups of sizes $1$ and $2$ from $5$ total? Your method gives $\binom{5}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{1}=30$, which is so small it is easy to verify directly.

$$\begin{array}{ccccc}
AB,C&AB,D&AB,E&AC,B&AC,D&AC,E\\
AD,B&AD,C&AD,E&AE,B&AE,C&AE,D\\
BC,A&BC,D&BC,E&BD,A&BD,C&BD,E\\
BE,A&BE,C&BE,D&CD,A&CD,B&CD,E\\
CE,A&CE,B&CE,D&DE,A&DE,B&DE,C\\
\end{array}$$

The corresponding book answer would be $\frac{5!}{2!\cdot1!}=60$, and demonstrably wrong.

Comment: Sounds right. Another way will be to first select 15 people and then select 7 (or 8) out of 15. C(50, 15) X C(15, 8) gives same answer as C(50, 8) X C(42, 7).

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways to partition a set of size $50$ into three subsets of sizes $7,8,35$ is $\dfrac{50!}{7!\, 8!\,35!}.$